# Best practice with Winforms that are externally updated

Tags: winforms, label

I am wondering whether it is a good idea to make labels public so other classes can change them and get their value. Is this a good idea? If not, how should it be done then?

Comment: It isn't, add a property to the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't make the label public.

It would be better to add a public method that was specific to what the label was displaying, and have it update the label.

For example, if your label was a "System status" label, you might want to add (to your Form/UserControl):

```
public void SetStatusInformation(string currentStatus)
{
     this.statusLabel.Text = currentStatus;
}
```

This allows you, later, to change how this information is displayed (in case you want to use a different control), and also simplifies your API, since the public methods are very clear to the user.

Answer (score 1):

it's a bad idea.  WinForms leaves many "what's the best way to do X?" questions open; and your best answer is to follow established patterns and practices (which aren't WinForms specific).

Read up on the MVP or MVC patterns.  They are both high-level patterns which focus on seperating out your UI-specific code from your business-logic.  Without this seperation your application can quickly become a maintenance nightmare, and things that should be simple get much more complicated.

For your specific scenario you would likely end up with a Model (your business-logic) which uses databinding to show it's data on the WinForms screen.  When a change on the UI occurs it would be the Model that receives the change, and that change would propagate to the UI via databinding.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping in a setter property or method because it's very possible you'll have to do something like add logging or re-call on window's main thread if the caller is from another one.  I found it easier to just always use code like the following when exposing functionality that lets clients update anything graphical.

```
public void SetStart()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
            {
                this.SetStart();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about getting, can this be in one function?

Comment: The problem only occurs when you have code in another thread try to call something that changes the appearance of your winforms window.  You'll know when it happens because an exception gets thrown.  Getting data doesn't require the safe guard as far as I know.